# ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI for Ribbon buttons

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have Ribbon control with multiple categories. Every category has one or several buttons. I add update handlers for all buttons in my ribbon:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
[...]
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_SERVER_INFO, &CMainFrame::OnServerInfoUpdate)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_SERVER_INFO2, &CMainFrame::OnAppStopUpdate)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_APP_START, &CMainFrame::OnAppStartUpdate)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_APP_STOP, &CMainFrame::OnAppStopUpdate)
[...]
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

ID_SERVER_INFO and ID_SERVER_INFO2 located in first category, ID_APP_START and ID_APP_STOP in second. So, ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI called only for buttons in first category, i.e. only for ID_SERVER_INFO and ID_SERVER_INFO2, but never for ID_APP_START and ID_APP_STOP.

Any ideas?

Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Rather than specifying multiple handlers, which could be hard to maintain, you might want to consider specifying one handler for each category and using the CCmdUI object that is passed to update the corresponding UI object.

Comment: This is not what i was asking about.